# Passing :test caused ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Both of these work:

```
Rails.application.credentials.development
Rails.application.credentials.send(:development)
```

However, the first one, `.test` works, but (:test) does not.

```
Rails.application.credentials.test
Rails.application.credentials.send(:test)
```

Why is :test special? What would make this not work?  I get

```
[5] pry(#<Cred>)>Rails.application.credentials.send(:test)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
from (pry):5:in `test'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test` is a private method defined in [`Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-test) module. `Kernel` is included in every ruby object.
When you call `.send(:test)`  this method is invoked and it requires 2 or 3 arguments.

It can be reproduced on other objects as well:

```
[15] pry(main)> :a.send(:test)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
from (pry):23:in `test'
[16] pry(main)> 1.send(:test)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
from (pry):24:in `test'
```

EDIT

I'm not sure what object is `credentials`, so I can't say it's the case for sure, but when you define `method_missing` it's invoked before private methods called directly, but not with `send`, see below:

```
class B
   def method_missing(*args)
     puts args
   end
end

pry> B.new.send(:test)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
from (pry):32:in `test'

pry> B.new.test
test
=> nil
```

EDIT2:

In general safer than `#send` [`#public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send). It won't let you call a private method and also it's caught by `#method_missing`:

```
[28] pry(main)> B.new.public_send(:test)
test
=> nil
```

Comment: Genius, so how do I call Rails.application.credentials.test, as variable? like send(:test)